# Angular variable set as value of HTML src attribute sending an unnecessary request to the server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

I have the following Jade markup, which uses AngularJS:

```
a: img.face(src='{{user.picture}}' ng-click='profile()')
```

The problem is that, when this page is rendered as HTML, a request is sent to the server like so:

```
https://somedomain.com/%7B%7Bi.picture%7D%7D
```

This is most likely occurring since the angular `$compile` has not kicked in by the time the request is made. How do I prevent this request from being made to the server?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak : Thanks, that worked! You could post your comment as an answer. I'll accept it since you were first to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `src` use angular's `ng-src` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-src` instead of `src`.

**Explaination**

`ng-src` is a built in directive that updates the `src` as soon as the input to `ng-src` changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
a: img.face(ng-src='{{user.picture}}' ng-click='profile()')
```

For further information:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc